# Dividir o banco de dados para vários clientes ou criar um pra cada um?

Tags: php, android, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um app para gerenciamento empresarial. Ele consumirá dados de um banco MySQL através de um Web Server.

Minha dúvida é: **Qual estratégia seguir para guardar os dados de cada cliente?**

Salvo todos os dados de todos os clientes em um único banco de dados e faço as regras para selecionar apenas dados do cliente autenticado; ou crio um banco de dados separado para cada cliente?

Caso a opção seja por criar um banco separado: **Existe uma forma de criar dinamicamente o banco de dados?**

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: É possível criar um banco de dados MySQL via php, caso você precisa de ajuda com isso posso postar uma resposta explicando, agora você tem que analisar os prós e os contras de cada solução.

Comment: Se poder me mostrar como criar eu agradeço!

Comment: Vou elaborar uma resposta ensinando a fazer isso e dando umas dicas.

Answer (score 7):

## Escolha um modelo "Multi-inquilino" ou "Multitenancy" adequado

Em uma aplicação em nuvem a pessoa/empresa que contrata o uso do sistema é chamado de inquilino ou "tenant". É importante dar esse nome ao invés de "cliente" para não confundir com a entidade "cliente" que normalmente tem nos sistemas.

A ideia básica é que você possa, de alguma forma, compartilhar os mesmos recursos com vários inquilinos reduzindo assim o esforço de ter que fazer uma instalação distinta para cada inquilino.
Esse compartilhamento tem vários níveis: hardware, aplicação, banco de dados, etc.

No caso de banco de dados existem basicamente três formas de você compartilhar o servidor de banco de dados:

1. Bancos Separados. Criar um banco de dados no servidor para cada inquilino.
2. Banco Compartilhado, Esquema separado. Criar um banco de dados único em que cada inquilino tenha um "schema" e as tabelas replicadas por inquilino.
3. Banco Compartilhado, Esquema compartilhado. Criar um banco de dados único com apenas um "schema" e criar uma coluna em todas as tabelas para o código do inquilino.

Analisando cada cenário você provavelmente já vai entender as vantagens e desvantagens de cada cenário em questão de manutenção e evolução do sistema para cada inquilino.

No [site da MS tem um artigo bem completo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa479086.aspx) sobre esse conceito onde você pode aprender mais e decidir sobre o melhor caminho.

Answer (score 5):

Não sei se há uma "melhor opção".

**Dividir banco de dados:**

**Prós**

Tudo armazenado em um único local.

Não tem necessidade de fazer "peripécias" para logar no banco.

Backup fácil - único arquivo

Não precisa ficar se preocupando em atualizar a estrutura de tabelas, campos, etc em vários bancos.

**Contras**

Toda query, terá a preocupação de fazer um filtro por cliente

Dados abertos para os demais clientes

Preocupação em sempre construir querys rápidas, porque alguns clientes podem ter poucos registros, outros, podem ter milhões...

Crescimento exponencial da base

---

**Criar um pra cada**

**Prós**

Dados de cada cliente "protegido" e em sua base

Quando o cliente quiser se desligar, o envio dos dados será mais rápido

Base de dados com tamanho (MB) de acordo com os dados do cliente

Base personalizada de acordo com a necessidade dele

Querys sem necessidade de preocupação com mais um filtro

**Contras**

Backup demorado - nada que não possa ser automatizado

Perda de dados pode ser um problema

Alterações de DML pode demorar, pois tem que fazer banco a banco.

Enfim, acho que tens que estudar o que você acha melhor pra sua aplicação. Infelizmente em algo você vai perder, isso será quase inevitável, só escolher o lado.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

É possível criar um banco de dados através do *PHP*, para isso basta você rodar um comando de criação de banco de dados, segue um exemplo simples:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = 'CREATE DATABASE my_db';
if (mysql_query($sql, $link)) {
    echo "Database my_db created successfully\n";
} else {
    echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
}
?>
```

**Pontos importantes na criação do banco de dados dinamicamente para cada Cliente**

Para fazer o uso disso você precisaria ter uma base de dados central com as informações dos seus clientes e suas respectivas bases de dados, assim você conseguiria associar cada Cliente a sua respectiva base.

Além disso é aconselhavel que cada Cliente tenha um usuário próprio de conexão com o banco de dados, com acesso somente a base central e ao seu banco de dados, pois isso tornaria seu sistema mais seguro e ficaria mais fácil de rastrear de onde veio uma alteração.

Da mesma forma que o banco de dados foi criado, você poderia também criar usuários do banco e dá permissões a eles.

Segue um link explicando os comando de [criação de usuários e permissões](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-criar-um-novo-usuario-e-conceder-permissoes-no-mysql-pt).